# Does $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\theta'}}$ make sense if $z$ is a function of $(r,\theta,\theta',r')$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question

Does $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\theta'}}$ make sense if $z$ is thought of as a function of $(r,\theta,\theta',r')$.

---

In finding acceleration in polar coordinates. I would like to find,

$$z'=(r'\cos (\theta)-\theta' r \sin \theta)'$$

I know how to do this using the product and chain rule of single variable calculus. However, I would like to exploit the chain rule of multivariable calculus.

Thinking of $z$ as $z(r,\theta,\theta',r')$ I can say:

$$z'=z_r r'+z_\theta \theta'+z_{\theta'}\theta''+z_{r'} r''$$

Blindly applying the formula sure enough gives me the right answer but in finding

$$z_{\theta'}$$

I hold all variables constant and vary $\theta'$.

That makes me question if the partial even makes sense because if $\theta$ is held constant then $\theta'$ cannot vary, it must be zero.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: isn't this the same trick as how you got $z$ in the first place? Strictly speaking, $r$ and $\theta$ are not independent (they both depend on time), so you could object to keeping one constant while varying the other; and yet you didn't question the formula at the very top (which, by the way, should say $z''$ on the left-hand side, shouldn't it? - you seem to be calling $z$ what most people would call $z'$)

Comment: Do you consider accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler, if $z = z(r, \theta, \theta', r') \in \mathbb{R}$ i.e $z: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ then to not abuse notation, let $x^i$ denote the coordinate variables where $1 \leq i \leq 4$. It follows from chain rule that,

\begin{align*} \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta '} &= \frac{d}{dx^3}\big(z(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4) \circ(r,\theta,\theta',r')\big)\\ \\ &=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^3} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^4} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x^3} \\ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x^3} \\\frac{\partial \theta'}{\partial x^3} \\ \frac{\partial r'}{\partial x^3} \end{pmatrix}  \\ \\ &= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^3} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^4} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x^3} \\ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x^3} \\ 1 \\ \frac{\partial r'}{\partial x^3} \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

Also, to the contrary of what's stated above, this works so long as $r,\theta, \theta',r': \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ are $C^k$-differentible i.e $k$ does not have to be $1$. If you assume $k=1$ you might as well use $d/dx^i$ instead of partial notation since $r,\theta,\theta',r'$ would be functions of one variable.